# React Parent to Children event Handing value passing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two component
Read Mode and Pagination

Read Mode Component

```
     state = {
            currentPdf:[],
            currentPage: null,
            totalPages: null,
            intialState:1,
        };
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
            this.onCurrentPageNo = this.onCurrentPageNo.bind(this);
            this.onTotalPage = this.onTotalPage.bind(this);

        }
        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.fetchPdfContent();
        }
        onCurrentPageNo(currentPageNo){
            this.setState({ currentPage: currentPageNo });
        }
        onChangePage(currentPdf) {
            this.setState({ currentPdf: currentPdf });
        }
        onTotalPage(totalpages){
            this.setState({ totalPages: totalpages });
        }
        gotoPrevPage = (currentTarget) => {
            if (this.state.currentPage > 1) {
                let prevPage = this.state.currentPage - 1;
                this.setState({ intialState: prevPage });
            }
        }

     render() {
       return (
          <button className="btn btn-primary prev-btn pageBtn" onClick={this.gotoPrevPage.bind(this)}>
                 <span aria-hidden="true" className="icon-ico_arrow-right icomoon"> Left </span>
          </button>
          <Pagination initialPage={intialState} items={pdfcontnet} onTotalPage={this.onTotalPage} onChangePage={this.onChangePage} onChangePageNo={this.onCurrentPageNo} />
        )
      }
```

Pagination Component

```
     constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { pager: {} };
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            // set page if items array isn't empty
            if (this.props.items && this.props.items.length) {
                this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);
            }
        }
        componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
            // reset page if items array has changed
            this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);
        }
        setPage(page) {
            console.log(page + 'pages');
            var items = this.props.items;
            var pager = this.state.pager;
            if (page < 1 || page > pager.totalPages) {
                return;
            }
            // get new pager object for specified page
            pager = this.getPager(items.length, page);
            // get new page of items from items array
            var pageOfItems = items.slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);
            // update state
            this.setState({ pager: pager });
            // call change page function in parent component
            this.props.onChangePage(pageOfItems);
        }
```

when i click the gotoPrevPage () initalState value need to pass

```
this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);
```

if i assign  componentDidUpdate() state I got

[image: cro]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `initialPage={intialState}` to `initialPage={this.state.intialState}` in your Read Mode Component render method.

PS: You should actually spell it `initial`, not `intial`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
onClick={()=>this.gotoPrevPage.bind(this)}
```

Comment: sorry its not working
My Problem Is
could not pass initial value this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);

Answer (score 0):

Your state object should be inside your constructor function in ReadMode. You should also be using `this.setState({})` to update state. You also shouldn't be trying to reload the entire DOM when a new item is added the way you are in the Pagination component via `commponentDidUpdate`. React uses a `virtual DOM` and doesn't need to reload every element on the page every time one element is updated. It looks like part of your problem is your App continuously updates and you're getting stuck in a never ending loop updating the DOM.

Also, you might not need Pagination to have local state. You could store the state/data in the parent container and just pass it to Pagination via `props`. React uses one-way data flow and you should familiarize yourself with passing `props` from a parent component to a child component.

Brush up on `state` and `lifecycle functions` by reading [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), get an understanding of how React uses the `virutal DOM` to update elements, and rewrite your App so that `state` is stored mainly in the parent component and is passed via `props` to the child component.

Overlooking basic React concepts and structuring your project in a less than ideal way is the source of your problems.